# How to send email to dynamic addresses in node-mailer using node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have a field called email in html page. I am getting this email from there by using `req.body.e` and i want to send some particular mails to this address(dynamic,whoever enter his email address mail is sent to his email). Only problem i am facing is i dont know what to write in " `to:` " in code.

```
app.post('/mail', (request, response) => {
  var e = request.body.e;

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'pjd1@gmail.com',
    pass: 'uni9039'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'pjd1@gmail.com',
  to: 'e' ,
  subject: 'Testing',
  text: `Only test`
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
})
```

This is html field

```
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="e" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
```

In this code i am getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input value is submitted as a regular form, you need to parse request body content with the appropriate middleware on Node.js side:

```
const express = require('express');
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post('/mail', (request, response) => {
  var e = request.body.e;
  console.log(e);
// ...the rest of code
```